# USPS API Returning Error - No error in XML

Tags: php, xml, curl, usps

I am using cURL to submit POST information to the usps shipping rate calculator.

```
$info = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<RateV4Request USERID='xxxx'>
    <Package ID='$aucid'>
        <Service>Priority</Service>
        <ZipOrigination>xxxx</ZipOrigination>
        <ZipDestination>$zip</ZipDestination>
        <Size>$size</Size>
        <Pounds>$pounds</Pounds>
        <Ounces>$ounces</Ounces>
        <Container>RECTANGULAR</Container>
        <Width>$width</Width>
        <Length>$length</Length>
        <Height>$height</Height>
        <SpecialServices><SpecialService>108</SpecialService></SpecialServices>
    </Package>
</RateV4Request>";

$array = array("API" => "RateV4", "XML" => $info);

$link = "http://production.shippingapis.com/ShippingAPI.dll";

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$link);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$array);
$answer=curl_exec($ch);
echo $answer;
curl_close($ch);
```

When I signed up for the USPS web tools, an email was sent with the USERID (I have replaced it with xs due to its sensitive nature).

In that same email, it was specified that Rate Calculation was allowed.
Here's the error that is returned:

> 80040B19XML Syntax Error:
>   Please check the XML request to see if it can be parsed.USPSCOM::DoAuth

I went ahead and took the XML that is echoed and plugged it into an `xmlvalidation.com` and it found no errors. I have also tried it without `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8">` line at the top.

Comment: Do you have a curl_init?

Comment: Are you sure that these values (like this one: `$pounds`) are getting updated with real values (numbers) and not just staying as the string "$pounds"?

Comment: @user2182349 Yes, it's above.

Comment: @jonmrich Yes the values are being passed in, I echoed it out at some point after putting its content type to text so the tags showed. That is the code i copied to the validation website.

Comment: Is your `$package_id` all numbers?

Comment: @jonmrich yes. It is equivalent to the id in the mysql database (unique to each shipment).

Comment: @A.Johnston Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Someone else had this issue and it was because of unescaped ampersands for him. http://stackoverflow.com/a/32911679. Another person found that their issue was because the tracking number was too long and PHP converted it to a different format. http://stackoverflow.com/a/26875878.

Answer (score 2):

PHP is turning the Package ID into scientific notation because it's just a big "number", so you need to stop that from happening by making it a string.

Instead of this: `<Package ID='$aucid'>`

Try this:  `<Package ID=\"".$aucid."\">`

You may also need to wrap that entire XML in `rawurlencode`

Comment: The `$aucid` is a two digit variable. I went ahead and put that in rawurlencode and I get the same error.